# JFrame in netbeans not implementing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to implement a new Jframe in net beans with

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("shooter");
```

however when it is run nothing is happening. I have run the same code in another IDE and it works fine however I am not seeing a JFrame on the screen. I ran a test to see weather everything was compiling and that there was no syntactical or lexical error so nothing seems to be wrong per say. 
Thanks.

Comment: It's impossible to say what you're doing wrong without more information. Where are you calling this code? Are you sure that the code is actually being run (a println(...) call would answer this for you)? Are you setting the JFrame to be visible? Does your class have a main method? Bottom line: Please improve your question.

Comment: yes ive run s.o.p and it works

Comment: OH wow! i had set visible to false! thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you've got it working, but please next time, ask your question in a way that does not assume that we can see code not shown. We are terrible at reading minds.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to provide an answer with the information you've provided, but I'll try my best.  By instantiating a new JFrame object, you aren't making it appear on the screen.

An example of creating and showing a new frame would look something like this

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
    frame.setSize(500, 500);  //This method will set the size of the frame to 500 by 500.
    frame.setVisible(true);  //This method makes the frame visible
```

I hope I could be of help.